# Get Folder Default Values JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, default-value

How can I get the default Values from a folder inside a library in SharePoint Online?

Comment: You can't currently, there is no endpoint/api for this that I am aware of

Comment: There has to be a way to access to the information of the folder. It doesn't make sense that they allow you to set Default Values and permissions to folders and then there is no way to access it

Comment: Coming from an on-prem migration to SPO with sites that had default values, I can tell you there is no API/endpoint for it as we had to recreate those post migration. Not everything in the platform is covered by an api or endpoint